# Обработчик для UserControl

Tags: c#, usercontrol

Есть 5 шт UserControl'ов, в каждом делаю ( разные названия классов )

```
public partial class UserControlClass : UserControl
{
    public UserControlClass()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
    }
private static UserControlClass_instance;

public static UserControlClassInstance
{
   get
   {
      if (_instance == null)
      {
          _instance = new UserControlClass();
      }

       return _instance;
    }
  }
}
```

По кнопкам распределяю следующие:

```
if (!Panel.Controls.Contains(UserControlClass.Instance))
{
  Panel.Controls.Add(UserControlClass.Instance);
  UserControlClass.Instance.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
  UserControlClass.Instance.BringToFront();
}
else
{
  UserControlClass.Instance.BringToFront();
}
```

Panel - Место куда будет показываться вызываемый UserControl

---

Можно ли создать один обработчик для работы с этими usercontroll'aми ?

Что-то типо такого:

```
public static void ControlVisible(Panel Panl, UserControl sv)
{
  if (!Panl.Controls.Contains(sv.Instance))
  {
    // UserControl sv - не правильный ( он не передаёт Instance )
     Panl.Controls.Add(SettingControl.Instance);
     sv.Instance.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
     sv.Instance.BringToFront();
  }
  else
  {
       sv.Instance.BringToFront();
  }
}
```

И по кнопкам ( в форме ) делать вызов:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ControlVisible(Control_Panel, UserControl.name);
}
```

2-ой вызов при нажатие на кнопку:

```
private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ControlVisible(Control_Panel, UserControl.name2);
}
```

Comment: так уже сделал как бы

Comment: @Санитариум,Я так первоначально и сделал, теперь хочу через один обработчик сделать, много строк кода выходить кидать на каждую кнопку проверку с `if-else`

Comment: всмысле 1 обработчик для кнопки хотите что ли

Comment: @Санитариум, 1 обработчик! С помощью которого можно будет вызывать нужным UserControl ( в форме - на каждую кнопку поместить один обработчик с вызовом нужного мне контрола ) Обновил вопрос!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну если правильно понял то так можно

```
void Check(Panel p, UserControl c)
        {
            if (p.Controls.Contains(p.Controls.OfType<UserControl>().Where(g => g.Name == c.Name).FirstOrDefault()))
                p.Controls.OfType<UserControl>().FirstOrDefault(g => g.Name == c.Name).BringToFront();
            else
            {
                p.Controls.Add(c);
                c.BringToFront();
            }
        }
```

Вызовы

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Check(panel1, new Red());
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Check(panel1, new Blue());
        }
```

Comment: То что нужно) Спасибо большое :*